# Need to find a Minimum date of the record in that period/sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the minimum status date for current status, in the below example 1.

the current status of the ID 1345 is 10, if i use min function i will get 7/12/19, Since i need to show the that when the id moved to the currently status recently. since that's the recent status of that record and the id moved to that status on 7/21 for that period.

Example 1

[image]

Example 2

The current status of the ID 3456 is 15, if i use min function i will get 7/15/19, Since i need to show the that when the id moved to the currently status recently for that period , in below case i need to get the last status date start = 7/18/19

[image]